# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Carbon/ Carbon.h': No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, vlc, libvlc

I'm getting the above error when trying to install libvlc:

```
C:\>easy_install vlc
Searching for vlc
Best match: vlc 0.0.1
Adding vlc 0.0.1 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Processing dependencies for vlc
Searching for appscript
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/appscript/
Best match: appscript 1.0.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/a/appscript/appscript-1.0.1.
tar.gz#md5=6447b3bef966613bb5ddaedfe32c4558
Processing appscript-1.0.1.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\michael\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-zjymfh\appscript-1.0.1\
setup.cfg
Running appscript-1.0.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\michael\appdat
a\local\temp\easy_install-zjymfh\appscript-1.0.1\egg-dist-tmp-ngrmwe
ae.c
c:\users\michael\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-zjymfh\appscript-1.0.1\appscrip
t_2x\ext\aetoolbox.h(17) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Carbon/
Carbon.h': No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsof
t Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2
```

I get the same error when using `pip` and am at a loss as to why it is happening.

Does anybody know what might be causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [package on pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vlc), it  for mac os only:

```
VLC (Mac OS) Python wrapper
```

There are a couple of  other options:

[vlc-python](https://github.com/geoffsalmon/vlc-python)

Or [vlc.py from wiki.videolan.org](https://wiki.videolan.org/Python_bindings)

Comment: also, if run `pip search vlc` ...then the second entry (or one of the entries really close to the top)  will show what @Pardaic Cunningham was talking about