# Python: VLC streaming error

Tags: python, windows, module, vlc

The module somehow managed to work [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28763906/vlc-import-error-no-module-named-appscript)

But now while trying to run the program:

```
import vlc
i = vlc.Instance('--verbose 2'.split())
p = i.media_player_new()
p.set_mrl('rtp://@192.168.1.109:8080/video')
p.play()
```

I get the following error:

```
[002d332c] main libvlc debug: VLC media player - 2.1.5 Rincewind
[002d332c] main libvlc debug: Copyright ■ 1996-2014 the VideoLAN team
[002d332c] main libvlc debug: revision 2.1.5-9-gb3fd0af
[002d332c] main libvlc debug: configured with ../extras/package/win32/../../../configure  '--enable-update-check' '--enable-lua' '--enable-faad' '--enable-flac' '--enable-theora' '--enable-twolame' '--enable-quicktime' '--enable-avcodec' '--enable-merge-ffmpeg' '--enable-dca' '--enable-mpc' '--enable-libass' '--enable-x264' '--enable-schroedinger' '--enable-realrtsp' '--enable-live555' '--enable-dvdread' '--enable-shout' '--enable-goom' '--enable-caca' '--disable-sdl' '--enable-qt' '--enable-skins2' '--enable-sse' '--enable-mmx' '--enable-libcddb' '--enable-zvbi' '--disable-telx' '--enable-nls' '--disable-dirac' '--host=i686-w64-mingw32' 'host_alias=i686-w64-mingw32'
[002d332c] main libvlc debug: using multimedia timers as clock source
[002d332c] main libvlc debug:  min period: 1 ms, max period: 1000000 ms
[002d332c] main libvlc debug: searching plug-in modules
[002d332c] main libvlc debug: loading plugins cache file C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins\plugins.dat
[002d332c] main libvlc debug: recursively browsing `C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins'
[002d332c] main libvlc debug: saving plugins cache C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins\plugins.dat
[002d332c] main libvlc debug: plug-ins loaded: 391 modules
[002d332c] main libvlc debug: translation test: code is "C"
[002d332c] main libvlc debug: CPU has capabilities MMX MMXEXT SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4.1 FPU 
[02b0419c] main input debug: Creating an input for 'rtp://192.168.1.109:8080/video'

***Repl Closed***
```

The path lines are highlighted in red by SublimeREPl as seen here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this package is for *nix not for Windows.

Comment: I found out that [this](http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=blob_plain;f=generated/vlc.py;hb=HEAD) can be used for Windows